# java Generalized Hypergeometric function

Tags: java, math, statistics

I am looking for a java library that can calculate generalized hypergeometric function (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_series). I looked at Apach Common Math, but did not find the function. Actually, I need the function to calculate the cumulative probability function for beta-binomial distribution (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta-binomial_distribution). If anyone knows a java package including the distribution, it would be good for me.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `org.apache.commons.math3.distribution.HypergeometricDistribution`
from [here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/distribution/HypergeometricDistribution.html).

[Download link](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/download_math.cgi).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I made a mistaken in the topic. It should be generalized hypergeometric function, instead of generalized hypergeometric distribution. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the wiki article that you posted, I think you can approximate the values of the hypergeometric function using this code that I wrote:

As a next step, it may be possible to estimate the error of the approximation.

```
/**
 * The generalized hypergeometric function is a convergent power series \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} c_i x^i
 * where the coefficients satisfy c_{n+1}/c_n = A(n)/B(n) for some polynomials A and B in n.
 * It is customary to factor out the leading term, so c_0 is assumed to be 1
 */

public class HypergeometricFunction {
    private final int degreeOfApproximation;
    private final double[] coefficientsOfA;
    private final double[] coefficientsOfB;
    private final double[] coefficientsOfHypergeometricFunction;

    public HypergeometricFunction(int degreeOfApproximation, double[] coefficientsOfA, double[] coefficientsOfB) {
        this.degreeOfApproximation = degreeOfApproximation;
        this.coefficientsOfA = coefficientsOfA;
        this.coefficientsOfB = coefficientsOfB;
        this.coefficientsOfHypergeometricFunction = generateCoefficients();
    }

    /**
     * @param x input
     * @return Approximation to the hypergeometric function by taking the first
     * {@code degreeOfApproximation} terms from the series.
     */
    public double approximate(double x){
        return evaluatePolynomial(x, coefficientsOfHypergeometricFunction);
    }


    private double[] generateCoefficients() {
        double[] coefficients = new double[degreeOfApproximation];
        coefficients[0] = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i < degreeOfApproximation; i++)
            coefficients[i] = (evaluatePolynomial(i, coefficientsOfA) / evaluatePolynomial(i, coefficientsOfB)) * coefficients[i - 1];
        return coefficients;
    }

    private double evaluatePolynomial(double n, double[] coefficients) {
        int length = coefficients.length;
        double out = 0.0D;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            out += coefficients[i] * pow(n, i);
        }
        return out;
    }

    private double pow(double a, int b) {
        double out = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < b; i++) out *= a;
        return out;
    }

}
```

If the series converges (and therefore provides a proper hypergeometric function), then `lim[c_i*x^i]` must be zero, so this should provide a reasonable approximation if you take `degreeOfApproximation` to be large enough.

The polynomials A and B are the ones referred to in the wiki article, and in order to use this code, you must provide arrays of coefficients for those polynomials to the constructor, along with your desired degree of approximation.

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: The problem with such "naive" approximations is that they haven't been tested and thus the error bounds are unknown. These often depend on the specific values at which the function is evaluated, and so need some internal "smarts" to take enough terms to converge. Also, this way of evaluating large polynomials tends to be numerically unstable....Which is why, I too was looking for a package that does this...Thanks!

Comment: Are you dealing with complex coefficients? If so, then it should be in a different question, because this one is about the beta-binomial. In the real case, the function is continuously differentiable on some radius of convergence (see wiki). So there is a Taylor series for the function which coincides with the one you would be approximating, and Taylor's remainder theorem actually does give a bound on the error. Where did you read that truncating a convergent power series is called a naive approximation? That's not a real term.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [GNU Scientific Library](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/) implementing [hypergeometric functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/specfunc.html#hypergeometric-functions) and [many random number distributions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/randist.html) -- unfortunately it is a C library.

Fortunately there is a [JavaCPP](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp)
 preset [available](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/tree/master/gsl) which means you can use it from java easily (it bundles native gcl library for windows/linux/android inside).

The [example](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/tree/master/gsl#sample-usage) did not work for me (it uses version `2.4-1.3.4-SNAPSHOT` of the library), but when modified to use version `2.2.1-1.3` (which is on maven central) it worked flawlessly.

My pom.xml is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-gsl-java</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <exec.mainClass>Example</exec.mainClass>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets</groupId>
            <artifactId>gsl-platform</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1-1.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Disclaimer: I am not a mathematician so please do validate my thoughts.

Good luck!